# text align not centering properly

Tags: html, css, image, nav, centering

So... I have a image in a div and then setting it to text/align but it's not 100% centered... the same thing with the navigation... it's close but not perfect... everything else is working fine. Can someone please give me a hand with this cause I'm going crazy. Thank you for all your anwsers in advance.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Projects</title>
            <link href="css2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        </head>
        <head>
            <div class="logo" >
                <img src="lg.png" alt="" width="180" height="178" class="logo"/>
            </div>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>mt</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="About.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="table" >
                <table width="900" height="200" border="0" cellspacing="7" cellpadding="9">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="row" > 
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="project1.html">
                                            <div class="raste">
                                                <img src="logos.jpg" alt="" width="300"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td> 
                                <li>
                                    <a href="project2.html">
                                        <div class="raste"> 
                                            <img src="elite.jpg" alt="" width="300"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </td>
                            <td> 
                                <li>
                                    <a href="project3.html">
                                        <div class="raste"> 
                                            <img src="time.jpg" alt="" width="300"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="project4.html">
                                        <div class="raste">  
                                            <img src="booksrie.jpg" alt="" width="300"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="project5.html">
                                        <div class="raste">
                                            <img src="log.jpg" alt="" width="300"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="project6.html">
                                        <div class="raste">
                                            <img src="log.jpg" alt="" width="300"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </body>
    </body>
 </html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
.logo {
    padding-bottom: 0.5%;
    text-align: center;
}
nav {
    font-family: "Proxima";
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    word-spacing: 80px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    padding-left: 50px;
    color: #000000;
}
li {
    display: inline;
    color: #000000;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
a:hover {
    color: lightgray;
}
a:active {
    color: black;
}
body {
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
table {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.raste img {
    height: 190px;
    width: 300px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    display: block;
    border: none;
}
.raste img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.079);
    transform: scale(1.079);
}
.table {
    display: table;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.raste {
    display: table-cell;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Proxima;
    src: url(Fonts/Proxima_Regular.otf);
}
```

Comment: Why do you have several `head` and `body` tags? And `head` tags are inside unclosed `body` tag.

Answer (score 0):

By using this jsfiddle `https://jsfiddle.net/hayrugh0/`

and inspecting the page, there is left-padding caused by ul element, its the default padding from the browser

attach this css rule and it should be centered

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

hope that makes sense

Comment: It's the logo in the div and nav

Comment: but the nav is really off

Answer (score 0):

All your images are contained in div tags so can you please define the image you want to center.Thanks

Comment: Just the nav... when i put ul { padding: 0,} it looks ok in dreaweaver but in the browser it still looks uncentered

Comment: Hello! i do not know the browser you are using but in mine the nav was centered.